# random image want to change src

Tags: javascript, random, image, src

I want to load 3 random images from an array that contains the names of all of the images. I did this but the `src` doesn't work. I don't know why!  Here is my code:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var longitut = images.length;
var num =1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*longitut);
var foto="\"image"+num+".jpg\"";
foto=foto.toString();

alert(foto);
document.getElementById("imatge1").src=foto;
```

Comment: Q: Have you checked this under a debugger (e.g. Firebug)?  What does it say?

Comment: `num = Math.floor(Math.random()*longitut);` and `foto = images[num];`

Comment: Thank's !! That's it , I tryed to do like u said but there was some mistake and it didn't work. But now it's running , thanks !

Comment: How can I make to change the img ID?

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake here,should be image1 not imatge1 should be:

```
 document.getElementById("image1").src=foto;
```

Also did you look into relative and absolute paths when linking?, as it could be a path error.

Comment: no you had a spelling mistake when referencing the image I believe. :)

Comment: Ah! no ,no ! hahahahaha
Imatge means image in Catalan, my dear lenguage :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove quotes from the string value:

replace

```
var foto="\"image"+num+".jpg\"";
```

with

```
var foto="image"+num+".jpg";
```

Also, make sure that your image element has the proper id attribute value. In your case it should be:

```
<img id="imatge1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code is correct, so it must be that you're either mistyping "image1" in the last line, or there's no  element in your page.

Just add this to your HTML page:

```
<img src="" id="imatge1" />
```